# How to reduce the image size in WebBrowser in Visual Basic

Tags: .net, vb.net, resize, webbrowser-control

When I open my first webpage in the WebBrowser control it is too large. I have to press Ctrl-minus to reduce it to a workable size. Is there some WebBrowser method that can reduce the size automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: `SendKeys.Send("^-")`